# Using $uibModalInstance in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

When opening a bootstrap ui modal, if you prefer to use a directive, rather than separately a `templateUrl` and `controller`, how can you then in the controller of the directive for the modal, access `$uibModalInstance` in order to close the modal or whatever you need to do? Also, how can we pass `items` without having to add it as an attribute on the template?

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.directive('myDirective', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {

    var controllerFn = ['$scope', '$uibModal', function ($scope, $uibModal) {

            $scope.names = ['Mario','Wario','Luigi'];

            $scope.openModal = function () {
                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    animation: true,
                    template: '<my-modal>',
                    size: 'lg',
                    resolve: {
                        items: function () {
                            return $scope.names;
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
        }];

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/Folder/my-directive.html',
        controller: controllerFn,
        scope: {
        }
    };
}])
.directive('myModal', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {

    var controllerFn = ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    }];

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/Folder/my-modal.html',
        controller: controllerFn,
        scope: {
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like that to send parameter to modal, add an element to array and give it back to directive.

```
// Directive who open modal
.directive('myDirective', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    var controllerFn = ['$scope', '$uibModal', function ($scope, $uibModal) {
        // Base array
        $scope.names = ['Mario','Wario','Luigi'];

        $scope.openModal = function () {
            // Modal instance
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: true,
                template: '<my-modal>',
                size: 'lg',
                controller: 'myDirectiveModalCtrl',
                controllerAs: '$modalController',
                resolve: {
                    // Provide namesInModal as service to modal controller
                    namesInModal: function () {
                        return $scope.names;
                    }
                }
            });
            // When modal close, fetch parameter given
            modalInstance.result.then(function (namesFromModal) {               
                $scope.names = namesFromModal;
            }, function () {
                // $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            });     
        };

    }];
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/Folder/my-directive.html',
        controller: controllerFn,
        scope: {
        }
    };
}])
// Modal controller 
.controller('myDirectiveModalCtrl', ['$uibModalInstance','namesInModal',
    function ($uibModalInstance, namesInModal) {
        // Use same name set in myDirective.controllerAs
        var $modalController = this;
        // Get provided parameter as service
        $modalController.names = namesInModal;
        // Add new element
        $modalController.names.push('peach');
        // Return modal variable when close
        $modalController.ok = function () {
            $uibModalInstance.close($modalController.names);
        };
        $modalController.cancel = function () {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };  
    }
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

In the directive's link function, $uibModalInstance is available on the scope object.

Comment: My mistake; I read that as 'How do you access $uibModalInstance from within a directive,' i.e. as opposed to from within the controller function, which I'd typically define in the usual way on the module with '.controller(...)', rather than in the way above. 

Should you nonetheless take the approach in the question to defining a controller within the directive definition, then I expect you could still pass $uibModalInstance as an arg to the controller function like you would otherwise, and then access it in the controller function body.